# how to transform file including text data into R tm's corpus format

Tags: r, tm, corpus

I just got acquainted to R's `tm` package. If there are separate .txt file in a folder, I understand how to transform these into a kind of corpus file
in R. But in my specific case I have all the textual data in one file. Each sentence in that file represents one document and has a preceding
phrase ID and sentence ID.
The .tsv-file looks like following:

> PhraseId  SentenceId  156061  8545    An intermittently pleasing but mostly routine effort . 156062   8545    An intermittently pleasing but mostly routine effort 156063 8545    An 156064   8545    intermittently pleasing but mostly routine effort .....

How can I transform text data out of such a file into `tm`'s corpus format?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(tm)

txt<-("PhraseId SentenceId 156061 8545 An intermittently pleasing but mostly routine effort . 156062 8545 An intermittently pleasing but mostly routine effort 156063 8545 An 156064 8545 intermittently pleasing but mostly routine effort ")

text.corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
```